# jQuery Button not executing onclick

Tags: web-services, jquery

I have a jquery function that loops through an xml and display it in a table and has buttons for each row so user can click on it and delete the record. Like this code I have attached;

```
$('#btnGetRecords').click(function() {
    $('#imgStatus').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/WebService1.asmx/GetRecords',
        data: '',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            parseXml(xml);
            $('#imgStatus').hide();
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            $('#imgStatus').hide();
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
});

function DeleteRecord(receiptNo) {
    alert(receiptNo);
    $('#divOutput').html('');
    $('#imgStatus').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/WebService1.asmx/DeleteRecord',
        data: 'receiptNo=' + receiptNo,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#delete_dialog').dialog('open');
            $('#imgStatus').hide();
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            $('#imgStatus').hide();
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
}

function parseXml(xml) {
    $('#divOutput').html('');
    var x = 1;
    var _html = '<br />';
    _html += '<table id="tblRecords" >';
    $(xml).find('Table').each(function() {
        var fname = $(this).find('FName').text();
        var lname = $(this).find('LName').text();
        var receiptNo = $(this).find('ReceiptNo').text();
        _html += '<tr>';
        _html += '<td>';
        _html += fname + ' ' + lname;
        _html += '</td>';
        _html += '<td>';
        _html += $('<input type="button" class="clsBtnDelete" id="btnDeleteRecord' + x + '" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteRecord(' + receiptNo + ');" />';
        _html += '</td>';
        _html += '</tr>';
        // alert(_html);
        x++;
    });
    _html += '</table>';
    $('#divOutput').append(_html);
}
```

But for some reason the delete button does not call the function to execute the delete. Any ideas how to make this to work. Thank you!

-Ryan

Comment: You have a click method for the delete button? Seems to be missing from your post.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `onclick` events after adding the table to the DOM. Something like:

```
$('#tblRecords .clsBtnDelete').click(DeleteRecord);
```

And have the DeleteRecord() function get the ReceiptNo from, for example, the <button>'s id:

- use `id="btnDeleteRecord_<ReceiptNo>"`
- have `DeleteRecord()` split the id value on `_`, and use the second (numeric) part

Comment: Thanks Joel but it still wont seem to work. Should I remove the part where it says onclick="DeleteRecord(' + receiptNo + ');" and on the code you gave me its missing an argument how do I add that using your code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the surface it looks fine, but since it looks like you are using ASP.NET I'm guessing that btnGetRecords is a asp:Button.

Look at the HTML you get from the server and make sure the button has the id you think it does.  In ASP.NET you usually see this in jquery selectors

```
$('#<%= btnSomething.ClientID %>')
```

Also, in IE table rows/cells are sometimes read only.

Comment: Hi wm_eddie! I using <input type="button" />.

Comment: In that case, then I'm not sure what the problem is, since like I said, the JavaScript code looks fine.  Have you tried using firebug?  Also, are you sure your JavaScript code has no syntax errors, those will usually stop the rest of the code from running.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
function parseXml(xml) { 
    $('#divOutput').html(''); 
    var _html = '<br />'; 
    _html += '<table id="tblRecords" >'; 
    $(xml).find('Table').each(function() { 
        var fname = $(this).find('FName').text(); 
        var lname = $(this).find('LName').text(); 
        var receiptNo = $(this).find('ReceiptNo').text(); 
        _html += '<tr>'; 
        _html += '<td>'; 
        _html += fname + ' ' + lname; 
        _html += '</td>'; 
        _html += '<td>'; 
        _html += '<input type="button" class="clsBtnDelete" id="btnDeleteRecord_' + receiptNo + '" value="Delete" />'; 
        _html += '</td>'; 
        _html += '</tr>'; 
    }); 
    _html += '</table>'; 
    $(_html).appendTo('#divOutput'); 

    $('#tblRecords .clsBtnDelete').click(function() { 
        alert('y');
        var cId = $(this).attr('id'); 
        var arr = cId.split('_'); 
        var receiptNo = arr[1]; 
        DeleteRecord(receiptNo); 
    }); 
}
```

I placed the block of code inside the parse XML. Thanks Joel!